# Why is std::move not [[nodiscard]] in C++20?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20, nodiscard

I've recently read about `[[nodiscard]]` in C++17, and as far as I understand it's a new feature (design by contract?) which forces you to use the return value. This makes sense for controversial functions like `std::launder` (nodiscard since C++20), but I wonder why `std::move` isn't defined like so in C++17/20. Do you know a good reason or is it because C++20 isn't finalised yet?

Comment: I know a reason that makes sense to me, but unless there's an official document explicitly saying why it isn't, that just turns the question to be opinion-based.

Comment: Why do you think it's not necessary for std::move to be [[nodiscard]]?

Comment: Because absolutely nothing bad (or at all) happens when you don't use it.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: similarly, nothing useful happens. It's the same as writing an empty statement, so `[[nodiscard]]` would help diagnose bugs. Also, nothing bad happens when `vector::empty()` is ignored, but that is marked `[[nodiscard]]` for obvious reasons.

Comment: You could write and submit a proposal paper to add it :)

Comment: @SebastianRedl That sounds like a great reason _to_ mark it `[[nodiscard]]`: "Hey, you did something completely pointless. Did you mean to do something else?"

Comment: @SebastianRedl that's not entirely correct though. Objects are said to be in a valid but unspecified state and only assignment operator could be used safely on them. So it's not "nothing bad (or at all) happens" in my opinion.

Comment: @bbalchev `std::move` doesn't move. Passing an object through `std::move` and ignoring the result does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Sure, but you can't use the parameter you gave to `std::move` except for `operator=`, so that's still an error, isn't it?

Comment: @bbalchev A separate `std::move(x);` is a no-op.

Comment: @bbalchev All `std::move` does is return an rvalue reference to the object; so that the object *can* subsequently be moved from *if* the reference is used that way.

Comment: You could make your own `bbalchev::move` which has a `[[nodiscard]]` on it.  I'd call mine `eljay::move_dammit`, but that's just me.

Comment: @GertArnold, I did but it is pending review

Answer (score 32, accepted):

AFAIK [P0600R1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0600r1.pdf) is the only proposal for adding `[[nodiscard]]` to the standard library that was applied to C++20. From that paper:

> We suggest a conservative approach:
>
> [...]
>
> It should not be added when:
>
> - [...]
> - not using the return value makes no sense but doesn’t hurt and is usually not an error
> - [...]
>
> So, [[nodiscard]] should not signal bad code if this
>
> - [...]
> - doesn’t hurt and probably no state change was meant that doesn’t happen

So the reason is that the standard library uses a conservative approach and a more aggresive one is not yet proposed.

Comment: I dunno. Not using the return value of `std::move` is always an error in my book, and should thus be nodiscard according to your citation: it either implies that the user forgot to use the return value, or that the call is unnecessary, since it has no effect.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Nobody has apparently shown the committee a common case in which the lack of nodiscard on `std::move()` causes actual errors. Consider bringing this up in the C++ standard-discuss mailing list.

Comment: @einpoklum Presumably like others, I don’t consider this issue urgent enough to waste the committee’s time on it (there are already too many new proposals). All I’m saying is that the lack of `[[nodiscard]]` is *probably* an oversight rather than a conscious decision motivated by the quote in this answer.

Answer (score 53):

The MSVC standard library team went ahead and added several thousand instances of `[[nodiscard]]` since VS 2017 15.6, and have reported wild success with it (both in terms of finding lots of bugs and generating no user complaints). The criteria they described were approximately:

1. Pure observers, e.g. `vector::size()`, `vector::empty`, and even `std::count_if()`
2. Things that acquire raw resources, e.g. `allocate()`
3. Functions where discarding the return value is extremely likely to lead to incorrect code, e.g. `std::remove()`

MSVC does mark both `std::move()` and `std::forward()` as `[[nodiscard]]` following these criteria.

While it's not officially annotated as such in the standard, it seems to provide clear user benefit and it's more a question of crafting such a paper to mark all the right things `[[nodiscard]]` (again, several thousand instances from MSVC) and apply them -- it's not complex work per se, but the volume is large. In the meantime, maybe prod your favorite standard library vendor and ask them to `[[nodiscard]]` lots of stuff?