# dynamic_cast a rvalue-reference unique_ptr?

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr, dynamic-cast

I have a class `Base` and a derived class `Derived`.
A function reads objects from a file descriptor and returns `Base` objects:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> readNextThing();
```

And in some place I need to downcast the return value of this function to Derived. This is relevant since the input unique_ptr is a rvalue-reference, so we don't copy the pointer, but move it. In this specific context I don't mind the object being destroyed if it's not of `Derived` subtype, I just need to detect that the downcast pointer is null in that case.

I could do:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
std::unique_ptr<T> dynamic_unique_cast(std::unique_ptr<U> && unique)
{
    T * t = dynamic_cast<T*>(unique.get());
    if(t) { unique.release(); }  //Transfer ownership
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(t);
}
```

and

```
std::unique_ptr<Derived> d = dynamic_unique_cast<Derived>(readNextThing());
```

1. Is there a built-in function for doing this?
2. Is there any risk of memory leak in the above code if an exception occurs?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` [doesn't work on `unique_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002641/dynamic-casting-for-unique-ptr) - there's no reason it couldn't work on an rvalue `unique_ptr`, except that perhaps the behavior in failure case would be non-obvious.

If this is a one-off case, you could go via `std::shared_ptr`, noting that it has an implicit constructor from `unique_ptr`:

```
auto ptr = std::unique_ptr<Derived>(
    std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(readNextThing()).release());
```

But I think your proposed utility function is clearer. Perhaps use the one from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21174593/downcasting-unique-ptrbase-to-unique-ptrderived?rq=1)?